# Native Storage not working on my Ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, cordova-nativestorage

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

...

constructor(
  private nativeStorage: NativeStorage
) {
}

setValue() {
  console.log('start')
  this.nativeStorage.setItem('prop', 'value')
  this.nativeStorage.setItem('prop2', 'value2')
  console.log('end')
}
...
```

when I call setValue() console.log('start') run, but the second does not work

if i call with .then still nothing in console

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
.then(
  () => console.log('Stored item!'),
  error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
);
```

Comment: have you added it to the app.modules.ts in providers?

Comment: yes providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    NativeStorage,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],

Comment: are you testing it on real device?

Comment: yes. the problem was not that. in my app i call login(user: User): Observable<any>{
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('1', '1')
    console.log('after')
    return this.http.get(this.url+'/auth.php?email='+user.email+'&password='+user.password)
    .pipe(tap(this.setToken), catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    )
  }    naviteStorage work here but when i call private setToken(response: AuthResponse | null) {
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('1', '1')
    console.log('after') } i get nothing

Comment: if you fixed it by yourself, post it as answer and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

everything is fine with the code

the problem was in the processing of the method that called setValue() from .pipe(tap(this.setValue()))inside which I could not call this.nativeStorage